# Data grid table in div (no fixed width)

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I have a data grid table (div based) that not in table format. I have done it in div based format with fixed width cell.

My problem

If I have add the column in the grid table, it will adjust like table format.

How can I do it?

[image: Data grid table here]

Above table I need to add the column but it's all fixed width cell, if I add extra column the
table collapses.

Comment: Without any source code, the community can't help you.

Comment: What is a "data grid table"? To me that implies data that would be best represented in tabular form, for which the `table` element is the obvious and best choice, but then you are talking about "div based"?

Comment: http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/tlt/2008/01/html-tables-are-not-eviljust-t.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible without table.

Just see below the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/BkwgY/2/

Comment: just put float:left in .tbl_cell